# Is there a better method for getting the CBV instance from Django's "as_view" mechanism

Tags: python, django

I have a simple test using Django's RequestFactory for a view. My view, sets some state within itself that I want to test (this is not a great example, but the point is I want to test some state in the view after the request is processed rather than parsing it out of HTML for no good reason):

```
def some_test(self):
    rf = RequestFactory()
    get_request = rf.get('/foo/')
    view = MyView.as_view()
    response = view(
        get_request,
        foo="hello",
        bar="world"
    )
    self.assertEquals( ??.sentence_to_display, "hello world")
```

Looking at the internals I can't see a way of getting the view instance used to process the request, `??` is my placeholder for the view instance which on `get` sets `self.sentence_to_display`

The best I could come up with was overriding `dispatch` in my CBV to do:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.META["__the_view__"] = self
    return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then altering my test such as:

```
def some_test(self):
    rf = RequestFactory()
    get_request = rf.get('/foo/')
    view = MyView.as_view()
    response = view(
        get_request,
        foo="hello",
        bar="world"
    )
    self.assertEquals( get_request['__the_view__'].sentence_to_display, "hello world")
```

While my example is arbitrary, my CBV has lots of methods that compute lots of things before rendering the HTML via a template. I trust Django to render the template, I don't want to test the template as such, I wish to test the CBV methods and the state of the instance after being invoked.

I really don't want to dig around the massive amount of output using BeautifulSoup when I just want to unit test the methods `get` uses to build the response.

Any better approaches? Am I missing the point?

Many thanks.

Django 1.6 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

`View.as_view()` does not create an instance. All it does is return a closure function that will create an instance when the view is called.

The best you can do is manually create an instance and prepare it the same way the closure function does.

```
def some_test(self):
    rf = RequestFactory()
    get_request = rf.get('/foo/')
    view = MyView()
    if hasattr(view , 'get') and not hasattr(view, 'head'):
        view.head = view.get
    view.request = request
    view.args = ()
    view.kwargs = {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 'world'}
    response = view.dispatch(get_request, *view.args, **view.kwargs)
    self.assertEquals(view.sentence_to_display, "hello world")
```

You can see the exact code Django uses to instantiate the view here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L62

Comment: Yep, I understand the mechanics. Feels like overkill to re-implement the inner function returned by as_view() however in the case of testing it probably keeps the view under test cleaner. Thank you for the suggestion.